# typeMismatch.server.environment while deploy spring boot 1.5 to Weblogic

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

This issue happens while deploy spring boot 1.5 to Weblogic.

Our Weblogic setup arguments while server starts, one of them is `-Dserver.environment=TESTB`, this cause the following error while deploy a web boot 1.5

I cannot remove that argument from the server since it may be used by other apps, but my app doesn't need that value. Anyway I can disabled it?

> [ERROR] Field error in object 'server' on field 'environment': rejected value [TESTB]; codes [typeMismatch.server.environment,typeMismatch.environment,typeMismatch.org.springframework.core.env.Environment,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [server.environment,environment]; arguments []; default message [environment]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.core.env.Environment' for property 'environment'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.core.env.Environment' for property 'environment': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]:org.springframework.validation.BindException:org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder$RelaxedBeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors

Comment: Why do you  use the same weblogic instance as the other apps? Have you tried using setting up the Node Manager, creating multiple weblogic instances and use one of them just for your app?

Comment: That’s our infrastructure design. We have hundreds of apps running on Weblogic Server Clusters, each cluster has some apps by business areas. I cannot ask infra to create a new instance just because of the typeMismatch issue, also the spring boot 1.2.8 works fine, it breaks on boot 1.5 and 1.4.